# Is there reason we are able to define [static const int] in a class definition, but not other static const types?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren't static const floats allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454019/why-arent-static-const-floats-allowed)

Is there any reason why this is not possible in C++? It confuses me.

```
static const int A = 100; //no error
static const float B = 2.0f; //error, can't define this type in class definition.
```

Comment: What the heck is ODR? :)

Comment: [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). The details surrounding "ODR-use" are foggy but can be mostly generalized to needing an object's address. **EDIT:** Sorry, I misunderstood the OP to mean static data members.

Comment: Please show a complete minimal example that is failing for something of the form of `B`, because I'm unable to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static constants of *integral* types can be *initialized* inside a class definition. That doesn't mean that the object actually exists, since you haven't provided a definition yet, but because the compiler knows the *value* of the object, you can sometimes get away with it.

That is, if you're not attempting to take the address of the variable or pass it by reference, but only use its *value*, then you don't need to provide a defintion at all, and the compiler simply substitutes the value wherever you use the variable.

C++11 introduces the `constexpr` keyword which allows you to do the same for a much wider variety of types.

Comment: so, static const int defined in a header behaves like a literal?

Comment: @xcrypt: Not "defined in a header", but "inside a class definition" (as Kerrek correctly said).  There is NOTHING special about headers or `#include`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, where did I mention #include? Please calm down. :)

Comment: @xcrypt: Then what exactly distinguishes a header from any other file, in your mind?

Comment: @BenVoigt I get your point. I am however taught a coding style where I nearly always use headers for class definitions, so I mixed up.

Comment: @Ben: ... the extension ... or lack thereof ...

Comment: @Xeo: Don't you mean "lack of extension"?