# Error declaring float constants

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm declaring a class which needs some public constants. My idea was declaring ones just like this:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  const int kIntConst = 1234;
  const float kFloatConst = 1234.567f;
  // ...methods...
};
```

This approach works fine for `int` constant but fails for the `float` one with the following error:

```
error C2864: 'MyClass::kFloatConst' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
```

Well, I **do** understand this error message. It says I cannot have a float (non-integral) constant declared in the class declaration. So, the question is: WHY!? Why it can be `int` but not `float`?

I know how to workaround this. Declaring `kFloatConst` as a static const member and later initialization in .cpp solves the problem but this is not what I'd like to have. I need a **compile time** constant (a one which can be optimized by compiler), not a constant class member which needs .obj file linking.

Using macro could be an option but macro doesn't have namespace and I don't like globally defined constants.

Comment: See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454019/why-arent-static-const-floats-allowed>

Comment: See this post's first (accepted) answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370283/why-cant-i-have-a-non-integral-static-const-member-in-a-class

Comment: You can initialize static const in-class.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454019/why-arent-static-const-floats-allowed, in particular Andreas Brinck's answer.

Comment: @Pubby I mentioned this workaround in the question. This approach is not acceptable for me.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Eventually I end up with declaring these constants via inline function member.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that you cannot have constants defined inside the class declaration.

Then there is an exception that integral constants *are* allowed anyway. So the `int` constant isn't the rule, but the exception.