# Undefined reference to static const double when used with complex.h

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

Here's the minimum code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

class Test {
    static const double dt = 0.1;
public:
    void func();
};

void Test::func() {
    cout << dt << endl; // OK!
    cout << dt*complex<double>(1.0, 1.0) << endl; // Undefined reference
}

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.func();
}
```

The noted line gives a `` undefined reference to `Test::dt' ``. I could make a temporary variable every time I want to multiply a complex number with `dt`, but that is inconvenient as I am multiply many static const members with complex numbers in my code.

My guess is that when multiplying `dt` with a complex number, it needs, for some reason, the address of  `dt` (i.e. `&dt`, which seems weird.

Any ideas why this error happens and how to make it work more elegantly than doing a `double temp = dt;` before every time I want to multiply it with a complex number?

Comment: This code should not compile.  Remove `static`.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it doesn't compile, it gives undefined reference. I need the static const variables though.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile because of the `static` keyword: `error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member ‘const double Test::dt’ of non-integral type` I can reproduce the undefined reference error after this compilation error gets fixed. This does indeed look like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: It doesn't **link**, a very different problem from a compile error.  Otherwise accurate, it can't link.  Do name the compiler you use so anybody that runs into the same bug knows how to deal with it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Interesting, on gcc 4.8.4 I can compile it well if I comment out the offending line.

Comment: I'm seeing the undefined reference error with gcc 6.1.1. This looks like a gcc compiler bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...how to make it work...?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

class Test {
    static const double dt;
public:
    void func();

};

//move initialization outside of class
const double Test::dt = 0.1; 

void Test::func() {
    cout << dt << endl; // OK!
    cout << dt*complex<double>(1.0, 1.0) << endl; // Undefined reference

}

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.func();
}
```

OR (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016780/undefined-reference-to-static-constexpr-char) for explanations)

```
class Test {
        static const double dt = 0.1;
    public:
        void func();

};
const double Test::dt;
```

OR (same trick as the one above has, but with c++11's `constexpr`)

```
class Test { 
         static constexpr double dt = 0.1;
    public:   
         void func();    

};                      
constexpr double Test::dt;
```

> Any ideas why this error happens...?

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static):

> If a static data member of integral or enumeration type is declared
>   const (and not volatile), it can be initialized with a initializer in
>   which every expression is a constant expression, right inside the
>   class definition...

So static data member could be initialized inside of class definition if it's of the type **int** or **enum** and declared **const**, which isn't your case. ( see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454082/3088216) for more info )

Why it's seems to be working for first line? Well, compiling with clang I got:

> warning: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const
>   double' is a GNU extension

So this float type initialization is extension of gcc compiler, and this extension is probably won't work with function's that expecting reference type argument (just a guess for now).

Also note, that this applies to c++98 only (c++11 has `constexpr` keyword that is addressing this issue)

Comment: Heh, I tried using `static constexpr` instead of `static const` in the code in OP, but the undefined reference still persisted.

Comment: about your last edit: if you switch `const`->`constexpr`, then it works and is almost exactly what I asked for in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `Test::dt` but not defined it somewhere. If you decide do define things outside of class declaration - you should be consistent:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

class Test {
    static const double dt;
    public:
    void func();
};

void Test::func() {
    cout << dt << endl; // OK!
    cout << dt*complex<double>(1.0, 1.0) << endl; // Undefined reference
}

const double Test::dt = 0.1;

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.func();
}
```

Comment: This will work, but as I have a lot of constants, it's more convenient and informative to keep the initialization in the header. Currently I still prefer the temporary variable solution.

Comment: Maybe simple `enum` would be better in your situation?

Comment: Apparently `enum` also gives an error when multiplying with a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

class Test {
    static const double dt;
    public:
    void func();
};

void Test::func() {
    cout << dt << endl; // OK!
    cout << dt*complex<double>(1.0, 1.0) << endl; // Undefined reference
}

const double Test::dt = 0.1;

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.func();
}
```