# Template Metaprogramming: "does not have integral or enumeration type"

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a "power" function using templates.

```
#define VAR_X 2.0f

template <int N> struct Power
{
    static const float ret = VAR_X * Power<N-1>::ret;
};

template <> struct Power<0>
{
    static const float ret = 1.0f;
};
```

I used a macro for the variable because floating point numbers can't be used as template parameters. When I try to compile with g++ 5.4.0, I get this:

```
tmptrig.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const float Power<1>::ret’:
tmptrig.cpp:35:28:   required from here
tmptrig.cpp:17:24: error: the value of ‘Power<0>::ret’ is not usable in a constant expression
     static const float ret = VAR_X * Power<N-1>::ret;
                        ^
tmptrig.cpp:22:24: note: ‘Power<0>::ret’ does not have integral or enumeration type
     static const float ret = 1.0f;
```

However, when I change the program to only deal with integers, it works fine.

```
#define VAR_X 2

template <int N> struct Power
{
    static const int ret = VAR_X * Power<N-1>::ret;
};

template <> struct Power<0>
{
    static const int ret = 1;
};
```

I know that floating point numbers cannot be used as template parameters, but (as far as I know) that's not how they're being treated here. Why doesn't the compiler like it when I use floats?

**Edit**: this is what my `main` looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << Power<1>::ret << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454019/why-arent-static-const-floats-allowed

Comment: Change `const` to `constexpr`.

Comment: The use of the macro here doesn’t help at all. Macros are just textually replaced: it’s still a float (and hence the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that floating point numbers cannot be constant expressions, because they can (despite not being admissible as template non-type parameters). The problem is that your code needs to mark them a such explicitly, or they cannot be initialized in the class defintion itself.

```
#include <iostream>

float constexpr var_x = 2.0f;

template <int N> struct Power
{
    static constexpr float ret = var_x * Power<N-1>::ret;
};

template <> struct Power<0>
{
    static constexpr float ret = 1.0f;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << Power<1>::ret << std::endl;
}
```

It's pretty much the same as your original intent, since `constexpr` implies `const`.

Clang gives a more helpful warning about your original code:

```
error: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const float' requires 'constexpr' specifier [-Wstatic-float-init]
    static const float ret = VAR_X * Power<N-1>::ret;
```

---

They can even be made constant expressions (and the results of meta-functions) in C++03, but that requires an out of class definition:

```
float const var_x = 2.0f;

template <int N> struct Power
{
    static const float ret;
};

template <int N>
const float Power<N>::ret = var_x * Power<N-1>::ret;

template <> struct Power<0>
{
    static const float ret;
};

const float Power<0>::ret = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Please remove that nonsense macro from your answer. It makes me weep. :'-(

Comment: I don't think C++03 constant expressions can contain variables of floating point types. (It seems that even in C++11 and later, non-constexpr floating point variables are still not allowed in a constant expression.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Done. Must admit I didn't really notice the macro. I blame tunnel vision.

Comment: @cpplearner - Const variables of any fundamental type were always constant expressions in C++, so long as their address wasn't taken. They had to be, or any suggestion to replace macros by consts (in headers too, no less) wouldn't hold any water.

Comment: Well [`const float x = 3.f; int a[(int)x];` does not compile.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X8kpYDa8ymDpQtdI) (And FWIW, [`int a [(int)+3.f];` does not compile with `-std=c++03`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jEkLfZqGiLhrp3EL).)

Comment: @cpplearner - And? Once you cast it isn't a constant expression anymore (you can look it up). Or are claiming that this proves `3.0f` isn't a constant expression either? Because it is by definition.

Comment: @cpplearner - To put a rest to it, [there's a working draft from 2005](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf), as close as you could get to C++03. Sub section 5.19 paragraph 3.

Comment: Well my point is given `const float x = 3.f;`, the value of variable `x` cannot be a constant expression (or part of one) in all versions of ISO C++ including C++03.

Comment: @cpplearner - You are wrong (on the first half of your sentence).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the `int` version works is because, well, it cheats.

From [[class.static.data]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#3)

> If a non-volatile non-inline const static data member is of **integral or enumeration type**, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression

For how to actually write correct code, check out [StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44871367/4832499)